# How can i access a element in a jquery object?

Tags: jquery

I have a basic jQuery question. I get an jquery object from a string:

```
var o = $(html_in_string)
```

Inside this jquery object, there is an element i want to have access to. How can i achieve that if i have the id of that element?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, `html_in_string` is a string containing html. In that case you can use `find()`.

```
var o = $(html_in_string).find("#some-id")
```

Comment: Thank you. That was pretty simple actually. I feel bad. :)